# error on gcloud beta run deploy not found

Tags: deployment, cloud, gcloud, camunda, beta

iam trying to deploy camunda on cloud run via google cloud sdk shell i followed the command as in this site https://medium.com/@ruslanfg/run-camunda-bpm-on-google-cloud-run-ecc59dc9fbc4
when i type last cmmand
(gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/camundacloud/camunda-demo --memory=1G)
and then appear service name: I typed my service name camunda then
error appear error not found requested entity was not found.
please help .

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the error after following the instructions in the [article](https://medium.com/@ruslanfg/run-camunda-bpm-on-google-cloud-run-ecc59dc9fbc4) you mentioned.

Please see my steps that lead to successful service deployment. If all steps are  followed, you should be able to run Camunda BPM on Google Cloud Run without issues:

1. Selected the required project with `gcloud config set project <your-project-id>`
2. Enabled beta components with `sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk` (alternatively, use `gcloud components install beta` as mentioned in the article you referenced)
3. Enabled Cloud Run - `gcloud services enable run.googleapis.com`
4. Set default Cloud Run region - `gcloud config set run/region <desired region>`
5. `gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/camundacloud/camunda-demo --memory=1G`

- For the prompt `Service name: (camunda-bpm-platform):` I entered `mycamunda`
- `Allow unauthenticated invocations to new service [mycamunda]? (y/N)?` - selected `Y`

Comment: thank u i tryed your steps  but when I type step number 6 service name and enter mycamunda the same error appere error<gcloud.beta.run.deploy> not found